# Getting "require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using NetBeans IDE 8. I have properly configured zendframework 1.12.1 in Netbeans
but Zend library file Autoload.php cannot load. I get this error:

> require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\RentAFlat-Zend\public\index.php on line 62

Here is my index.php

```
ini_set("display_errors", E_ALL);

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Comment: What is configured in NetBeans won't affect the running of your application - that's just for class/method awareness for autocomplete etc. You need to check what is in `get_include_path()` after line 15 (i.e. when you reset the include path). Debug from there: does the path include the location of the `Zend` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php <- you need to find out where that file is in relation to index.php

Zend is building and creating an include path for you ( that is the fallback folder that PHP looks for classes is the specified local path doesn't contain the file your are trying to require). It is then setting it so you do don't have to use full paths every time you need to require a file from the zend library. However this is an old way of doing things as namespaces combined with autoloaders are pretty much defacto now. e.g Zend 2.0 +

I would suggest your next port of call would be the following.

Debug the following and echo out the various lines to make sure that it points to the containing folder 'library' where the zend files should live. Secondly at the bottom of that snippet you pasted. There is 1 comma too many. I have put it in square brackets for you to remove

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path()[,]
)));
```

I would then echo out the get_include_path() afterwards to make sure that in that string is an absolute path to the 'library' folder. If its not there, or the path is wrong you know its not setting the include path properly. Fix that, then is should require the file properly

HTH